# Understanding an inequality in the proof

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, inequality, proof-explanation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I believe my question is on some very **elementary computations** (i.e., this is probably answerable even if you don't know what is the subgaussian norm $\| \cdot \|_{\psi_2}$ etc. However, do let me know if you want clarifications on the definitions. I will update the post if needed). Nevertheless, I will post the statement and the proof that I am trying to understand here for context. This is the statement of the proof:

[image]

This is the proof that I am trying to understand (I will state my specific question after this picture):

[image]

**In particular**, I am confused on how to check the very last inequality $\| X_{uv} - X_{wz} \|_{\psi_2} \leq C \| Y_{uv} - Y_{wz} \|_2$ for some constant $C$ large enough.

**Attempts**: Through computation (squaring both sides of the $\| X_{uv} - X_{wz} \|_{\psi_2}$ inequality and expand the quadratic terms on the right hand side), I noticed that it suffices to show
$$
\| u - w \|_2 \| v - z \|_2 \operatorname{rad}(S)\operatorname{rad}(T) \leq C \| u - w \|_2^2 \operatorname{rad}(S)^2 + \| v - z \|_2^2 \operatorname{rad}(T)^2 = C\| Y_{uv} - Y_{wz} \|_2^2
$$
for some $C$ large uniformly for all $u,w,v,z$. However, I do not see why this would be true. Perhaps we can do something with the boundedness of the set $S$ and $T$? I am not entirely sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @MartinR Please point out exactly what is wrong with the images in this question - they are perfectly readable. The number of people who uses screen readers is pretty much negligible.

Comment: @IraeVid: The reasons are given in that link. That is a policy on this site, I did not make up it myself. (And users with visual impairments or other disabilities should not be excluded, no matter how many or few there are.)

Comment: @MartinR You can direct users to software such as [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/), which is an OCR tool for Latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$\| X_{uv} - X_{wz} \|_{\psi_2} \leq \| u - w \|_2 \operatorname{rad}(S) + \| v - z \|_2 \operatorname{rad}(T)$$
and
$$\| Y_{uv} - Y_{wz} \|_2^2 = \| u - w \|_2^2 \operatorname{rad}(S)^2 + \| v - z \|_2^2 \operatorname{rad}(T)^2,$$

it suffices to show that $$\| u - w \|_2 \operatorname{rad}(S) + \| v - z \|_2 \operatorname{rad}(T) \lesssim \Big[\| u - w \|_2^2 \operatorname{rad}(S)^2 + \| v - z \|_2^2 \operatorname{rad}(T)^2\Big]^{1/2}.$$

This follows from the standard estimate $(a+b)^2\leq 2a^2 + 2b^2$ applied with
$a = \| u - w \|_2 \operatorname{rad}(S)$ and $b=\| v - z \|_2 \operatorname{rad}(T)$.